# Given Contraction find unique fixed point

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,d) be a complete metric space, and let $T:X \rightarrow X$ be a function such that $T^{p}$ is a contraction for some $p\geq 1$. Show that T has a unique fixed point.

Proof: To find uniqueness $\alpha$ must be less than 1 where by definition of contraction $d(T(x_{1}), T(x_{2})) \leq \alpha d(x_{1},x_{2})$.

We will show a sequence convergent to a fixed point. So define $T^{p}:X \rightarrow X$ by $x_{p+1} = T(x_{p})$ for some $p\geq 1$. So we must show $(x_{p})$ is a Cauchy Sequence. If $p \geq q \geq 1$ then by definition of contraction, we have

$ d(x_{p},x_{q})= d(T^{p}x_{0}, T^{q}x_{0})
\leq \alpha^{q}[d(T^{p-q}x_{0},x_{0})
\leq \alpha^{q}[d(T^{p-q}x_{0},T^{p-q-1}x_{0})+ d(T^{p-q-1}x_{0},T^{p-q-2}x_{0})+....+ d(Tx_{0},x_{0}) ]
\leq \alpha^{q} [\Sigma^{p-q-1}_{r=0}] d(x_{1},x_{0})
\leq (\dfrac{\alpha^{q}}{1- \alpha})d(x_{1},x_{0}), 
 $
thus $x_{p}$ is Cauchy.

Given the metric space (X,d) is complete, the $(x_{p})$ converges to limit $x \epsilon X$.

$ Tx= T \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} x_{p}= lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} Tx_{p} = \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} x_{p+1}=x $

Assume $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are two fixed points, then we can say

$ d(x_{1},x_{2}) \geq 0$

$d(T(x_{1}),T(x_{2})) \leq \alpha d(x_{1},x_{2}).$

Since $\alpha < 1 $, then $d(x_{1},x_{2})=0$, so $x_{1}=x_{2}$. Thus, we have a unique fixed point.

Is my proof correct? I looked at something similar but the $p \geq 1$ kinda threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually by a simple trick you can prove the $p ≥ 1$ case from the classic $p = 1$ case. $T^p$ is a contraction so there is unique $x$ such that $T^p(x) = x$. But then $T^p(T(x)) = T(T^p(x)) = T(x)$ so $T(x)$ is also fix-point. But by uniqueness we have $T(x) = x$.

Comment: Is this a shorter version of what I have or is what I have completely off?

Comment: @RuthGutierrez: You just prove the standard theorem for $T$ a contraction since you assume $d(T(x_1), T(x_2)) ≤ α d(x_1, x_2)$.